# Modifying value in list of lists with condition

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a list of lists:

```
 batches = [['der\n', 'und\n', 'die\n', 'des\n', 'mit\n', 'in\n', 'nach\n', 'eine\n', 'wird\n', 'auf\n'], ['bei\n', 'im\n', 'den\n', 'das\n', 'von\n', 'einer\n', 'sich\n', 'dem\n', 'ist\n', 'über\n']
```

etc. There's 1 list of 10 lists, each containing 10 strings/tokens (I just provided a sample).

I have another list with some nouns and I want to change any string in batches if it matches a string in the list of nouns. But I want the structure of batches to remain the same, how can I do this?

```
    for x in batches:
        for y in x:
            if y.rstrip() in noun_list:
                y += '- this is a noun'
```

But this doesn't change anything. 
I also tried a list comprehension:

```
[''.join(y + '- this is a noun') if y.rstrip() in noun_list else [''.join(y)] for x in batches for y in x]
```

But the structure changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings in Python are immutable. You need to replace the list element, not update the temporary variable `y`. So you need the list index, which you can get with [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for x in batches:
    for i, y in enumerate(x):
        if y.rstrip() in noun_list:
            x[i] += '- this is a noun'
```